Cannot attach EBS to multi-container ECS Task
Goal: Use a single EBS volume in a task that has multiple containers for a centralized storage
What I have tried: I have created a task definition composed of two containers. When I run the task one container always fails with the following error happening in container_1:
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '': VolumeDriver.Mount: docker-legacy: Mount: ebs_test: failed: no device name returned

The second container will start successfully though.
If I remove container_2 from the task definition, the task with only container_1 start successfully and the EBS volume works as expected. The volume shows up in the /mnt directory as expected. So it doesn't appear to be an issue with container_1, the instance, or any permissions.
root@d2dc53cd2a2b:/# ls /mnt/
ebs_test

I get the same results if I remove container_1 from the definition. contianer_2 correctly acquires the EBS volume at /mnt:
bash-4.2# ls /mnt/
ebs_test

Code:
locals {
  volume_name = "ebs_test"
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_test" {
  availability_zone = "us-west-2a"
  size = 51

  tags = {
    Name = local.volume_name
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ebs_test_task" {
  family = "ebs_test_task"
  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.execution_role.arn
  placement_constraints {
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "ec2InstanceId == specific_id"
  }

  volume {
    name = local.volume_name
    docker_volume_configuration {
      scope = "shared"
      autoprovision = true
      driver = "rexray/ebs"
    }
  }

  volume {
    name = "efs_test"
    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id = module.efs_mount.file_system_id
      transit_encryption = "ENABLED"
      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.efs_access_point.id
      }
    }
  }

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = "Container_1"
      memoryReservation = 512
      essential = true
      image = "<ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container_1:latest"
      portMappings = [
        {
          hostPort = 80,
          containerPort = 80
        }
      ],
      mountPoints = [
        {
          containerPath = "/efs_test"
          sourceVolume = "efs_test"
        },
        {
          containerPath = "/mnt/${local.volume_name}"
          sourceVolume = local.volume_name
        }
      ]
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group = "task_name"
          awslogs-region = data.aws_region.current.name
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "container_1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name = "Container_2"
      memoryReservation = 512
      image = "<ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/container_2:latest"
      portMappings = [
        {
          hostPort = 81,
          containerPort = 80
        }
      ],
      mountPoints = [
        {
          containerPath = "/efs_test"
          sourceVolume = "efs_test"
        },
        {
          containerPath = "/mnt/${local.volume_name}"
          sourceVolume = local.volume_name
        }
      ]
      essential = true
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group = "task_name"
          awslogs-region = data.aws_region.current.name
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "container_2"
        }
      }
    },
  ])
}

I have been using this repo as a reference but they only use a single container in the task definition: https://github.com/markgllin/ecs_with_ebs
Updated Finding
I am able to get work around this by putting each container in it's own task and starting them sequentially. However, if I try to use threads to call run_task as fast as possible, one of the containers experiences the error:
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '': VolumeDriver.Mount: docker-legacy: Mount: ebs_test: failed: no device name returned

This might indicate some sort of timeout or busy error for the EBS volume?
